# Am trying to create a matrix to compare CY and PY

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am creating a matrix in powerbi to compare current and previous years by month, also to show the % variance, which is the CY-PY/CY.
this is what am getting [image]

what i want to achieve is this [image]

Comment: Maybe a good idea to include how you got this, also some raw data is needed to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

As very limited information is provided:

- If the year(2020 and 2021) are columns for each month's values. It would be better to first declare Variance% as a custom column in the edit query(under 'add column' and give the formula of variance).
- Select Column 2020,2021 and Variance% ->Right click->Unpivot selected column, this would define all these columns as attributes and store values as Value.
- Save and close changes made in the edit query and in the page select Matrix graph and build the graph.